# How to fix timeout issue with drawing a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to draw a graph, but when I run the code, it says the compiler timed out and fails to run. This is the code:

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, thick, minimum size=7mm},
]

\node[roundnode]        (leftcircle)        {(1\; 2)}
\node[roundnode]        (rightcircle)       [right=of leftcircle] {(2\; 3)}

\draw[->] (leftcircle.east) -- (rightcircle.west)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a couple of `;` and `$` signs. In more detail, every path needs to be terminated by `;`, and `\node` as well as `\draw` commands start a path. And in order to use `\;` you need to switch to math mode, i.e. add appropriate `$` signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, thick, minimum size=7mm},]
 \node[roundnode]        (leftcircle)        {$(1\; 2)$};
 \node[roundnode]        (rightcircle)       [right=of leftcircle] {$(2\; 3)$};
 \draw[->] (leftcircle.east) -- (rightcircle.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to draw an arrow from the right node which doesn't meet another node? So if I want to show a general graph with n vertices, how do I do that without drawing every node? And can I include ellipses in the graph?

Comment: @MonzurRahman Sure, just add `\draw[->] (rightcircle.east) -- ++ (1,0);`. BTW, the anchors in `\draw[->] (leftcircle.east) -- (rightcircle.west);` could get dropped, i.e. you could use `\draw[->] (leftcircle) -- (rightcircle);`, but they do not hurt.